# Linker error - Undefined symbols

Tags: visual-studio-2013, cmake, qt5.5, log4cplus

**Greeting**

I've download and compiled `log4cplus` in `VS2013` (1.2.0-rc3) . Compilation was fine (both debug and release) I've tried to use it in my code but I get lots of link errors, nothing I tried didn't remove them. I'm using the same includes from the log4cplus project, and the libs I've compiled and i still get these.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MYPROJECT, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>utility.cpp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class log4cplus::Logger __cdecl log4cplus::Logger::getInstance(class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > const &)" (?getInstance@Logger@log4cplus@@SA?AV12@ABV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@@Z)
1>utility.cpp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class log4cplus::Logger __cdecl log4cplus::Logger::getInstance(class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > const &)" (?getInstance@Logger@log4cplus@@SA?AV12@ABV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@@Z)
1>device.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class log4cplus::Logger __cdecl log4cplus::Logger::getInstance(class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > const &)" (?getInstance@Logger@log4cplus@@SA?AV12@ABV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@@Z)
1>path_tree.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class log4cplus::Logger __cdecl log4cplus::Logger::getInstance(class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > const &)" (?getInstance@Logger@log4cplus@@SA?AV12@ABV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@@Z)
1>cim_manager.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class log4cplus::Logger __cdecl log4cplus::Logger::getInstance(class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > const &)" (?getInstance@Logger@log4cplus@@SA?AV12@ABV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@@Z)
1>pin_manager.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class log4cplus::Logger __cdecl log4cplus::Logger::getInstance(class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > const &)" (?getInstance@Logger@log4cplus@@SA?AV12@ABV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@@Z)
1>nautilus.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class log4cplus::Logger __cdecl log4cplus::Logger::getInstance(class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > const &)" (?getInstance@Logger@log4cplus@@SA?AV12@ABV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@@Z)
1>ravis.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class log4cplus::Logger __cdecl log4cplus::Logger::getInstance(class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > const &)" (?getInstance@Logger@log4cplus@@SA?AV12@ABV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@@Z)
1>ncr.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class log4cplus::Logger __cdecl log4cplus::Logger::getInstance(class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > const &)" (?getInstance@Logger@log4cplus@@SA?AV12@ABV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@@Z)
1>wincore.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class log4cplus::Logger __cdecl log4cplus::Logger::getInstance(class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > const &)" (?getInstance@Logger@log4cplus@@SA?AV12@ABV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@@Z)
1>atm_utility.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class log4cplus::Logger __cdecl log4cplus::Logger::getInstance(class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > const &)" (?getInstance@Logger@log4cplus@@SA?AV12@ABV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@@Z)
1>banqit.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class log4cplus::Logger __cdecl log4cplus::Logger::getInstance(class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > const &)" (?getInstance@Logger@log4cplus@@SA?AV12@ABV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@@Z)
1>grg.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class log4cplus::Logger __cdecl log4cplus::Logger::getInstance(class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > const &)" (?getInstance@Logger@log4cplus@@SA?AV12@ABV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@@Z)
1>king_teller.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class log4cplus::Logger __cdecl log4cplus::Logger::getInstance(class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > const &)" (?getInstance@Logger@log4cplus@@SA?AV12@ABV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@@Z)
1>supervisor_manager.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class log4cplus::Logger __cdecl log4cplus::Logger::getInstance(class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > const &)" (?getInstance@Logger@log4cplus@@SA?AV12@ABV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@@Z)
1>registry_manager.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class log4cplus::Logger __cdecl log4cplus::Logger::getInstance(class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > const &)" (?getInstance@Logger@log4cplus@@SA?AV12@ABV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@@Z)
1>device_manager.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class log4cplus::Logger __cdecl log4cplus::Logger::getInstance(class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > const &)" (?getInstance@Logger@log4cplus@@SA?AV12@ABV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@@Z)
1>atm_factory.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class log4cplus::Logger __cdecl log4cplus::Logger::getInstance(class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > const &)" (?getInstance@Logger@log4cplus@@SA?AV12@ABV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@@Z)
1>database_manager.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class log4cplus::Logger __cdecl log4cplus::Logger::getInstance(class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > const &)" (?getInstance@Logger@log4cplus@@SA?AV12@ABV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@@Z)
1>user_interface.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class log4cplus::Logger __cdecl log4cplus::Logger::getInstance(class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > const &)" (?getInstance@Logger@log4cplus@@SA?AV12@ABV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@@Z)
1>fit_manager.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class log4cplus::Logger __cdecl log4cplus::Logger::getInstance(class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > const &)" (?getInstance@Logger@log4cplus@@SA?AV12@ABV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@@Z)
```

What i'm missing here ?!

**Thanks in Advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem!!

I had to set `/Zc:wchar_t` to `set_target_properties` in my project `CMakeLists.txt`.

```
set_target_properties(MYPROJECT PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/W2 /Zc:wchar_t")
```